# What's the point of App ID's and Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: iphone

As I understand it, an App ID is an code that's unique for an single application. Every time I start developing an new application, I have to create a new App ID.

But I don't get it what's up with that "provisioning profile". Do I need one for each single app? What's that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provisioning profile contains a list of devices that are allowed to run or debug your code. Everything is verified with a digital signature, which ultimately lets Apple control distribution. This is why you need to jailbreak in order to get apps from sources outside the App Store.

Comment: oh so jailbroken iPhones don't need that provisioning profile in order to run an app?

Comment: But jailbroke apps can't be sold or distributed on the app store, and can cause issues if(when) Apple cracks down on them.

Answer (score 2):

It's to protect the end users, by having a way to validate apps and their origin. It also serves as a centralized system to control development. On windows most apps use GUIDs for this, but they don't have any centralized info about them. Apple does, which is a pain at times, but it's a valid effort in the end.

Comment: So each app has it's own App ID and it's own Provisioning Profile?

Comment: Yes indeed, each app has a AppID, but the provisioning is per device/developer and finally for submission, so posibly more than one on a team.